# What are the most important mantras/hymn, stotrams and chants for Ram and Krishna?

Tags: krishna, mantras, rama, stotra, hymn

My parents tell me that Nama Ramayanam (Shuddha-Bramha) is by far the most important hymn for pleasing and worshipping Sri Ram.

What are some other hymns, mantras and stotrams dedicated to Shri Ram that invoke the most amount of bhakti within us and are effective?

And what are the most important ones for Sri Krishna?